# Isolating within a simple equation

Tags: simple-functions

excuse the perhaps misleading title. I didn't know what else to call it.

I need some help with isolating "FG" within this equation:
Vol=(1,055-FG)⋅131,25

I would prefer a step-by-step guide, so I needn't ask again. (not using too complicated words as my english isn't that good)

Very simple, and perhaps not something fitting for this site, sorry.

Comment: do you have anything tried so far? Do you know Vol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "isolating", but if you mean "solving for", then it is relatively straightforward

$$
Vol=(1055-FG) ⋅ 13125 \ \text{(original equation)}\\
\frac{Vol}{13125} = 1055 - FG \ \text{(divide by 13125)}\\
\frac{Vol}{13125} + FG = 1055 \ \text{(add FG on both sides)}\\
FG = 1055 - \frac{Vol}{13125}
$$

Comment: Yeah my bad, thanks for the help though!